# how can we validate a password as css

Tags: html, validation, password-protection

How can I display the icon "valid", if the "comfirm password" field text is identic to "password" text? Simillar to the name and email fields in the example. 
Here is the css code for email verification and name:

```
input[type=text]:required:valid,[type=email]:required:valid,textarea:required:valid{
background:url(valid.png) 90% center no-repeat #FFF ; 
}
```

Example:
http://data.imagup.com/10/1160658139.JPG

Comment: I think that you might need javascript for this if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 2):

CSS is **not** a programming language.

You have to validate your fields on server-side or even on client-side with Javascript.

With the current HTML5 implemation in modern browser you can check for the value of inputs. But as far as i know you can't check for the same value only with pure css.

```
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" required pattern="[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}"
     title="Password numbers consist of 3 uppercase letters followed by 4 digits."/>
```

Take a look at [**The constraint validation api**](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api)

Here is an example of how you can check emails for similarity using the api mentioned above.

```
<label>Email:</label>
<input type="email" id="email_addr" name="email_addr">

<label>Repeat Email Address:</label>
<input type="email" id="email_addr_repeat" name="email_addr_repeat" oninput="check(this)">

<script>
    function check(input) {
        if (input.value != document.getElementById('email_addr').value) {
            input.setCustomValidity('The two email addresses must match.');
        } else {
            // input is valid -- reset the error message
            input.setCustomValidity('');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `:valid` and `:invalid` are acceptable pseudo-selectors, in the case of html5-forms.  They come with the stipulation that you're using the built-in regex attribute on the input-element, itself (which guarantees that only html5 browsers which fully support this module are going to support this styling, but still).